# Rails webpacker:uninstall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I installed stimulus into my Rails 6 app using `rails webpacker:install:stimulus`, but then decided I don't need it.  What is the command to uninstall something that was installed via webpacker?  I tried `rails webpacker:uninstall:stimulus` but that didn't work, and googling only led me to people asking how to uninstall webpacker itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `webpacker:install:stimulus` task does three things:

1. Adds `stimulus` to the dependencies in `package.json`
2. Creates `app/javascript/controllers` (plus a couple of sample files)
3. Adds `import "controllers"` to the bottom of `app/javascript/application.js`

So, presumably removing those three things will suffice to uninstall.